# "Вертоград" – насколько верно словарное определение?

Tags: значение-слов, лексикография

Обратилась коллега с вопросом. Просит помочь разобраться с определением слова "вертоград", которое нашла в одном словаре – каком, не указала.
В свою очередь адресую этот вопрос вам, дорогие коллеги.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pMrJ.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

Есть другие словари и тексты, которые поясняют, что такое **вертоград**.

**[Медицинская энциклопедия](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_medicine/6219/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4)**:
(*истор.; церковнославянское **«сад»***)
лечебник, содержащий описание растений, минералов и животных, используемых для лечения больных, а также прописи лекарств.

Архитектурный словарь:
   1. Огороженный сад.
   2. Плодовый сад.
   3. Цветник.
   (Термины российского архитектурного наследия. Плужников В.И., 1995)

Краткий церковнославянский словарь:
- сад огороженный.

[**Полный церковно-славянский словарь**](http://www.orthodic.org/?searchCs=&searchRu=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4&type=ru&go.x=0&go.y=0):
садовник  — вертоградарь
Сад — Вертоград
сад, вертоград  — верт

На церковнославянском языке слово **сад** — вертоград, а **садовник**, возделыватель сада — вертоградарь. Думаю, что в словарь, указанный Вами, вкралась ошибка.

*Чрез нее идет дорога,

А за ней **казенный сад**;

Этот **сад** известен много, –

Это – Пензы **вертоград**!*

Михаил Иванисов. Казенный сад (**1860-1870гг.**)

У Даля в статье [**рай**](http://www.superbook.org/DICTIONARY/DAL/r.htm):
*м.* первобытный сад, вертоград, жилище прародителей Адама и Евы.

Comment: Ошибка эта связана с не очень внимательным и неквалифицированным копированием определения Даля. Это прекрасно продемонстрировано в предыдущем ответе. Только автор неудачной словарной статьи пропустил "ветроградарь"

Comment: Вы спрашивали "насколько верно словарное определение?". @Сибиряк дал в своем ответе выдержку из словаря Даля. Но ведь гарантии, что за полтора века кто-то что-то в своих ссылках на него не напутал, нет. Поэтому я и привела данные из разноплановых и разновременных источников. О **причине** возникшей ошибки Вы не спрашивали. Сейчас **однозначно** нельзя сказать, **каким именно образом** она возникла.

Comment: Вы,безусловно, правы. :)

Answer (score 2):

Даль с этим определением [согласен](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%A1%D0%942/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4).

> **Вертогра́д** *м. церк.* сад, *особ.* плодовый; виноградник; вертоградный, садовый; ***вертогра́дарь*** *м.* садовник.

Comment: Однако у Даля "вертоград" не определяется как "садовник". Здесь налицо не очень внимательное знакомство с принципами составления, структурой словарной статьи у Даля. Он приводит ряд слов того же корня, обладающих совершенно разными значениями в одном словарном гнезде. В современных словарях - совершенно иной принцип. В данном случае мы имеем дело с очевидной лексикографической "развесистой клюквой".

Comment: @БорисБобылев Верно. Садовника я проглядел.

Comment: Такое впечатление, что при сокращении словарной статьи другого источника (а таковых много) авторы-составители не заметили однокоренное слово для "садовника".